# Is there any performance advantage using non-equi join instead of where clause in Oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, join, where-clause

I've been studying Oracle SQL non-equi join and while there are so many different use cases, I noticed that joining tables using a range of values with non-equi join is basically the same as using WHERE clause.

Code from a great non-equi join tutorial [here](https://learnsql.com/blog/sql-non-equi-joins-examples/)

```sql
SELECT r.id, r.name, h.id, h.address, h.rent, h.bedrooms
FROM renters r
JOIN houses h
ON h.district = r.preferred_district
    AND h.rent BETWEEN r.min_rent AND r.max_rent
    AND h.bedrooms >= r.min_bedrooms
WHERE h.id NOT IN (SELECT house_id FROM deals);
```

In the above example, I think `AND h.rent BETWEEN r.min_rent AND r.max_rent` part and `AND h.bedrooms >= r.min_bedrooms` can be placed in WHERE clause and return exactly the same result.

So what's the point of using non-equi join here?

My guess is that by applying constraints during the join operation would be more performant since the joined table would be smaller.

Is my guess correct? Is there anything I'm missing?

Thanks in advance mates.

Comment: You'll get the same result, and same performance. but why move join conditions to the WHERE clause?

Comment: @jarlh In this context, I thought using non-equi join rather than a simple WHERE filter was confusing because non-equi join is not that common.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to get insight in such topic is to use `EXPLAIN PLAN`. You get an overview of the join type and the used *access* and *filter* predicate.

Here an example of the (bit simplified) statement using part of the conditions in the `where` clause

```
EXPLAIN PLAN  SET STATEMENT_ID = 'jara2' into   plan_table  FOR
SELECT r.id, r.name, h.id, h.address, h.rent, h.bedrooms
FROM renters r
JOIN houses h
ON h.district = r.preferred_district
where h.rent BETWEEN r.min_rent AND r.max_rent;
    
 
SELECT * FROM table(DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY('plan_table', 'jara2','ALL'));
```

Result - cut for brevity

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation          | Name    | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT   |         |     1 |   208 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  HASH JOIN         |         |     1 |   208 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL| RENTERS |     1 |   104 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   3 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL| HOUSES  |     1 |   104 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------
 
   1 - access("H"."DISTRICT"="R"."PREFERRED_DISTRICT")
       filter("H"."RENT">="R"."MIN_RENT" AND "H"."RENT"<="R"."MAX_RENT")
```

*The exact same excution plan you'll see for the original statement with the full join condition without `where` clause.*

You can your guess **is not correct**, in both cases Oracle makes a *hash join* with the equal predicate (`access predicate for id 1`)  and then throw away the rows that does not match the `filter predicate for id 1`)

So the swaping of predicates between  the join consition and `WHERE` clause **is not relavent for non-equi joins** (except for estetics, readability and *correct SQL*), but BTW is *very relevant* for `OUTER JOINS` *as you can get a different results*.

Comment: Wow, such empirical and clear proof that the two queries should yield the exactly same result. I didn't (and still don't) really know how to properly interpret the execution plan so I'll look into it but for now it seems clear that the optimizer behind the scene somehow made the two queries to have the same execution plan.

Answer (score 3):

Functionally, when you have an inner join, there is no difference between specifying predicate conditions in the `WHERE` clause or in the join conditions.  Prior to Oracle adopting the SQL 99 join syntax (in 9i if memory serves), all conditions had to be specified in the `WHERE` clause-- there was no `JOIN` keyword.

From a performance standpoint, there should be no difference.  The optimizer should produce the same query plan whether the conditions are specified in the `WHERE` clause or as part of the `join`.  As the number of tables involved increases and the number of potential plans grows, that may not be strictly true in all cases.  But you shouldn't expect consistently better or worse performance from different ways of writing the same query.

The benefit of putting the conditions in the `join` clause is readability.  In general, queries are easier to read when you put all the conditions that tell you how table A relates to table B together in the `join` condition.  If you put some of the conditions in the `WHERE` clause, Oracle will give you the same result but it's likely to take the human reading your query longer to understand what results you're asking for.  This is particularly true as your SQL statements start to get more complicated.  If you were joining 5 or 6 tables, for example, a human reader would potentially have a dozen or so predicates in the `where` clause that related to different joins tens of lines apart.  Keeping all that in your head as your reading the SQL statement is a lot harder than if the `join` clause contains everything you need to know to relate two tables together.

Comment: (Minor comment) The explicit `JOIN` syntax was introduced already in SQL-92.

Comment: @jarlh - True.  But I believe when Oracle added support for the `JOIN` syntax, it was as part of supporting the SQL 99 standard.